# Electrum personal server rescan-script.py

Tags: electrum, server

when i run the rescan script i get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bitcoin/electrumserver/eps/rescan-script.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/bitcoin/electrumserver/eps/rescan-script.py", line 67, in main
    rpc.call("rescanblockchain", [height])
  File "/home/bitcoin/electrumserver/eps/electrumpersonalserver/jsonrpc.py", line 58, in call
    raise JsonRpcError(response["error"])
electrumpersonalserver.jsonrpc.JsonRpcError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'Method not found'}
```

I am very new to this, so please explain for beginners :).

Comment: What version of Bitcoin Core are you using?

Comment: Running "version": 160200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the wallet is enabled in Bitcoin Core. Electrum Personal Server relies on the wallet. Check that you are not starting Bitcoin Core with `-disablewallet` or that `disablewallet=1` is not in your bitcoin.conf file.